# Подскажите jquery плагин совместимый с autocomplete ui?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Плагин, который был по выбору из autocomplete вставлял labels в поле инпут друг за другом

Comment: Руки даны, для того, чтобы писать, а не искать плагины.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var object = [{
    label: "Tag 1"
  }, {
    label: "Tag 2"
  }, {
    label: "Tag 3"
  }];
  $("#t").autocomplete({
    source: object,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $("#tags").append("<div class='tag'>" + ui.item.label + "<span class='close'>x</span></div>");
      $('.close').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tag {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed #dfdfdf;
}
.close {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="t">
<div id="tags"></div>
```

[Посмотреть на jsbin](http://jsbin.com/okaQOyAq/1/edit)

Comment: почти это. только имелось ввиду чтобы вставлять в инпут несколько значений

Answer (score 0):

Нужное нашел здесь - https://github.com/maxwells/bootstrap-tags